# how do i match multiple column from different dataset in R

Tags: r, match, matching

I need to fetch teacher name by matching the subject and board from studentdata and tutordata.
Code--

```
Studentdata$Tutor.name <- Tutordata[cbind(
  match(Studentdata$Subject, Tutordata$TSubject),
  match(Studentdata$Board, colnames(Tutordata))
)]
```

**Tutordata**

```
Tname TSubject TBoard
A     Physics   IB, IGCSE
B     Physics   CBSE,JEE mains
C     Math      JEE mains
D     Math      IGCSE
E     Physics   ICSE
```

**StudentData**

```
StudentName Board   Subject
X          IB       Math
Arjun      IB       Physics 
Rehana     IGCSE    Physics 
Rashid     CBSE     Math    
Ashika     JEE mainsMath    
Aagya      ICSE     Math
```

All the variables are factors in the above dataset.

Comment: *"I need to fetch"* and *"Code--"* do not suggest any problems, it helps to be clear by including actual warnings, errors, or data mangling. Looking at your data, there is no match here: there is only one `IB`, and it is both a substring (so not "just" `IB`) and is not on the same row as `Math`. Either your data can be improved so that there is actually a match, or you need to better explain what *"fetch"* means to you in this context. (Hint: I'm thinking a form of `merge` or `dplyr::*_join` might work, but again it does not seem right.) What is your expected output given this input?

Comment: sorry about the vague question. I have edited the question.could you help now? New to R programming

Comment: I'm glad you were given an acceptable answer. When you ask another question, it might be useful to include your expected output as well, in order to help validate/verify that others understand your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, you can try to split `TBoard` column into separate rows and then do a join.

```
library(dplyr)

tidyr::separate_rows(Tutordata, TBoard, sep = ",") %>%
   mutate(TBoard = trimws(TBoard)) %>%
   right_join(StudentData, by = c('TBoard' = 'Board', 'TSubject' = 'Subject'))
```

However, there doesn't seem any matches in your data.

Comment: sorry about the vague information. I have edited the question now.Problem is since the tutor board is a factor, i dont know now to parse through the data. I have attached the image of the output and input below. Sorry ,new to R programming

Comment: no. Not matching even when there is a match. Student rehana gets NA for tutor although there is a match. how to parse through a factor?